# Android studio is slow in gradle building

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio is getting slow in grade building process.I noticed this problem after updating to new version 3.5.Is there any ways to
speed up the building process?

Comment: are you using crashlytics?

Comment: i am not using crashlytics, but i am using firebase, one signal, retrofit

Comment: You may consider removing some dependencies which are not used for real. --> build.gradle (app)

Answer (score 8):

1- Make sure you’re using the latest version of `Gradle`. Generally with every new update there is a significant improvement in performance.
Note: Java 1.8 is faster than 1.6. Make sure it’s updated too.

2- Try to minimize the use of modules. There are many cases where we need to fork the library to modify it to fit according to our needs. A module takes 4x greater time than a jar or `aar` dependency. This happens due to the fact that the module needs to be built from the scratch every time.

3- Enable `gradle` Offline Work from `Preferences-> Build, Execution, Deployment-> Build Tools-> Gradle`. This will not allow the `gradle` to access the network during build and force it to resolve the dependencies from the cache itself.

> Note: This only works if all the dependencies are downloaded and
>   stored in the cache once. If you need to modify or add a new
>   dependency you’ll have to disable this option else the build would
>   fail.

4-Open up the `gradle.properties` file from the root of your project. Add the following lines of code in it.

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

`Gradle` daemon is a background process. Adding this would consume some extra memory while building.

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

The above line of code enables compilation of multiple modules at the same time. Besides that it also gives us other benefits such as;

Re-using the configuration for unchanged projects
Project-level is up-to-date checks
Using pre-built artifacts in the place of building dependent projects
Adding the following line of code also aids us in speeding up the build.

```
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Another important property is;

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

The above line is used to allow Java compilers to have available memory up to 2 GB (2048 MB). It should only be used if you have available memory more than 2 GB.

This is how the `gradle.properties` file should look like:

[image]

5- Avoid dynamic dependencies such as
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'.
Dynamic Dependencies slow down your build since they keep searching for the latest builds every time. To improve the performance we need to fix the version in place.

6- Use only those dependencies that you need. For example google maps dependency, instead of importing , like :

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:17.0.0' 
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradle build speed depends on a lot of factors including the specification of your machine as well as your build type and android studio settings. You can check out [this article](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-speed-up-your-slow-gradle-builds-5d9a9545f91a) on how to reduce your build time or go through the steps in the [Android developer website](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build).

**Personal experience**:

When I faced this issue, *enabling offline mode* drastically reduced my build time. The only problem is that I have to toggle this setting (on and off) every time I want to add a new dependency and this almost made me go berserk on several occasions. However, if properly handled, this helps a great deal.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

you can set file->setting->search 'Gradle'-> check 'use local gradle distribution' and check 'offline work'.. in android studio. it will improve gradel building time.

Note: In newer version of Android studio, View->Tool Windows->Gradle->Toggle button of online/offline