# Android Gradle build is taking lot of time to execute the code

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, gradle

Earlier, build was taking only 2 to 3 minutes to run, but now it's taking 8 to 11 minutes. I found in Task Manager, OpenJDK platform uses high memory. But I did not get any resource to overcome this. Please give me suggestion to solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information [Android studio is slow in gradle building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57745750/android-studio-is-slow-in-gradle-building[here])

Also you could update your Android Studio's Gradle plugin if you hadn't done it before.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for it even for me too some times take 10 - 15 mins. But earlier it takes about 15 - 20 mins but after I added some codes that reduce somewhat time.

First open your manifest file and add

```
android:largeheap="true";
```

And add this line in your Gradle properties file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5120m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

android.enableBuildCache=true
```

Comment: I'm not sure it perfectly reduces your build time but it may help somewhat

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i already have this configurations, still it is slow